# Javascript object in an other object

Tags: javascript

I searching for an hour now (w/o any success), that how can I define an object in an other object (in javascript):

```
function UserStat(arr) {
    var arrx = arr;
    this.day = function(dateofday) {
        //Some code going here which results will be stored variables like:
        this.a = someInnerFunction();
        this.b = someOtherFunction();
    }
}
```

I'd like to access these variable when I create an instance of the outer function, somehow like this if this is possible:

```
var value = new UserStat(arr1).day('2012-10-20').a
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Just have the "day" function `return this;` at the end.

Comment: The basic problem is that, by using `this`, you are binding `a` and `b` variables to the `UserStat` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you wanted to use the dateofday variable, but this would work:

```
function UserStat(arr) {
    var arrx = arr;
    this.day = {
        a: someInnerFunction,
        b: someOtherFunction
    };
}

new UserStat().day.a();
```

So would this:

```
function UserStat(arr) {
    var arrx = arr;
    this.day = (function(date){
        var obj = {};
        obj.a = someInnerFunction;
        obj.b = someOtherFunction;
        return obj;
    }(dateofday));
}
```

Or even this:

```
function UserStat(arr) {
    var arrx = arr;
    this.day = new function() {
        this.a = someInnerFunction,
        this.b = someOtherFunction
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Basicly I need an instance of this `var tst = new UserStat(arr)` which stores data from `arr`, but when I call `tst.day(date)` I'd like to receive every info about the date i passed in from the `arr` object. Like `tst.day(date).a` as an integer for example.

Comment: Thanks, finally I figured out base on your answers second part, but I think there is no need for the `(dateofday)` part at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
function UserStat(arr) {
    var arrx = arr;
    this.day = function(dateofday) {
        //Some code going here which results will be stored variables like:
        var dayFunc = {
            a: someInnerFunction,
            b: otherFunc           
        }
        return dayFunc;
    }
}
​
```

Comment: This will assign a function to UserStat.day that, itself, creates a new object when called and returns it. He probably intended day to be the object.